# 2003 Mitsubishi Lancer won't crank despite new battery and alternator

Tags: battery, mitsubishi, no-crank-no-start, lancer

This is a 2003 Mitsubishi Lancer.

Within the last 3 weeks, we have replaced the battery and the alternator. The car ran fine for about a week after replacing the alternator and now it won't start.

We put a batter charger on it for about 2 hours last night and 3 hours this morning.  When we tried to start it, it made one click and that was it.

I also noticed that the light that shows a door is open doesn't even come on anymore. When you hook up jumper cables and start to put the 2nd one on, as soon as it touches the battery it makes the same one click sound.

Any ideas?

Comment: click sound with the key on, engine off? or key off, engine off? You need to recheck your battery, and have your car tested for parasitic draw.

Answer (score 1):

First test is the battery voltage.  A simple multi-meter that you can get almost anywhere for less than $20.00 is sufficient.  You should be somewhere close to 12.6 volts.  If so, then the battery isn't the issue.  If it's low, then yes try the [parasitic draw test](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-a-Parasitic-Battery-Drain) next then.

The next step would be to clean the battery terminals and all battery connections.  I had a friend with this same issue last Sunday.  Battery showed 12.7 volts and everything looked fine on the terminals.  Turns out they were oxidized but didn't show it.  A quick cleaning of the terminals and the problem was solved.

It's been my experience that if you are hearing clicks when you try to start the car, it's either a dead battery (or close to it) or a bad connection to the battery.